# bitwise multiplication to reduce gas cost

Tags: solidity, gas, optimization, bit-manipulation

This is the multiplication method from the `SafeMath` library.

```
/**
* @dev Returns the multiplication of two unsigned integers, reverting on
* overflow.
*
* Counterpart to Solidity's `*` operator.
*
* Requirements:
* - Multiplication cannot overflow.
*/
function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
  // Gas optimization: this is cheaper than requiring 'a' not being zero, but the
  // benefit is lost if 'b' is also tested.
  // See: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/pull/522
  if (a == 0) {
    return 0;
  }

  uint256 c = a * b;
  require(c / a == b, "SafeMath: multiplication overflow");

  return c;
}
```

Could this be done using the [shift operators](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.5.3/types.html) in Solidity to reduce the amount of gas consumed?

[image]

If yes, what would the necessary changes look like?

Comment: yeah, it is a standard way to divide numbers in all languages starting from Solidity and ending with C, but the only problem is that shifts only divide by multiples of 2

Comment: what i wanna do is make it cheaper. how about this --> https://medium.com/wicketh/mathemagic-full-multiply-27650fec525d

Comment: and how much are you gonna save on math operations? these are not expensive. I would go for SSTORE, it is spending around 20k Gas. If you pack many variables into single SSTORE operation you are going to save by 20k gas on each SSTORE

Comment: how can i exactly calulate the difference in gas between this safemath operation and the one from that medium article

Comment: @smatthewenglish the easiest way to compare gas costs across different contracts is to use [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org) by pasting the contracts in there and monitoring the gas reported in the logs at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Regarding making SafeMath cheaper, I am actually [working](https://twitter.com/PaulRBerg/status/1381282089534885892) on a math library that incorporates Remco's [mulDiv](https://xn--2-umb.com/21/muldiv/) as we speak.